# Pass Data Between Custom Native Activity in WorkFlow

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I'm writing a workflow designer and I want to Send A Data From An Activity To Others without using Inargument on my custom activity so 
I write A custom Native Activity and add a property to my context like this

```
context.Properties.Add("Name",Value  );
```

and for calling the property i use this code:

```
 var dynamicinarg = (string)context.Properties.Find("Name");
```

but when im Debugging  it the dynamicinarg is null .
how can i fix it?

Comment: Execution properties can only be used by the descendants. In other words, if you're adding the *Name* property on PropertySetterActivity that same property can only be used by the PropertySetterActivity's descendants. Your use case seems weird. You're probably doing something conceptually wrong.